# Do I need more than one random slope?

Tags: r, mixed-model, glmm, lme4-nlme

When constructing a GLMM in R, do I need more than one random slope if I "see" that slopes differ for multiple continuous variables?

In my case, I am analysing the number of plant species (`S`) found across several large areal units (biomes) in southern Africa. I have several continuous predictors, mainly climatic parameters. For this I use a (G)LMM formula like this:

```
myModel <- lmer(S ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + (1|biome), ...) # random intercept model
```

Now, I see that slopes for biomes differ strongly:

[image: Example plot for differences in slope for S1000 across biome units]

Hence: I would adjust my formula to:

```
myModel <- lmer(S ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + (X1|biome), ...) # random intercept - slope model
```

However, if I now see that also `X2` and `X3` have differing slopes across the variables, should my model look like this?

```
myModel <- lmer(S ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + (X1|biome) + (X2|biome) + (X3|biome), ...) 
# random intercept - (multiple) slope model
```

I ask this question, because I am simply not sure whether this last formula makes the model too complicated or might be not "allowed" in a statistical sense, in short: I am simply "not sure" and I did not find any examples where more then one slope was estimated.

Comment: A couple notes: You say that you have count data & that you are fitting a GLMM, but you are using `lmer`, not `glmer` & you aren't specifying `family=poisson` in your code. Also, it may be that there is a curvilinear relationship b/t temp & S, rather than a varying slope. The right biomes go up, the left go down & those that span the middle of the range seem to go up & down somewhat.

Comment: yes you are right, I should have specified the family argument, however, this example is only for illustration purposes. the actual dataset is much more complicated. Sites are then random effects nested in a larger site. thanks for pointing on this.

Comment: I see that this post is two years old, but that plot looks great. How do you make it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does make sense, but you have to be a little bit careful in setting up the model.  The way you've written the model,

```
 S ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + (X1|biome) + (X2|biome) + (X3|biome)
```

it implicitly incorporates an intercept term with each random effect slope.  You could write it as

```
 S ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + (1|biome) + (X1+0|biome) + (X2+0|biome) + (X3+0|biome)
```

which will estimate the intercept and all of the slopes separately. (It might be a good idea to center your covariates as recommended by [Schielzeth 2010](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210X.2010.00012.x/abstract) ...)

Alternatively, in principle (but see below for caveats) you could use

```
 S ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + (X1+X2+X3|biome)
```

which would fit correlations among the slopes.

More fundamentally, however, I would consider (recommend?) fitting the among-biome variation as fixed effects rather than random effects,

```
 S ~ (X1+X2+X3)*biome
```

(then you could just use `lm` instead of `lmer`).  Because you only have samples for 6 biomes, you will be estimating random-effects variances (and in the case of `(X1+X2+X3|biome)`, a 4x4 random-effects variance-covariance matrix) from only 6 parameters.

One more comment: from your data, it looks like you have multiple observations with the same covariate (temperature range) value, which suggests that you are getting multiple observations from the same site.  I would think about incorporating site as a random effect ...

Comment: (+1.) Out of curiosity, why wouldn't a model like: `S ~ (X1+X2+X3)*biome + (1|biome)` be reasonable? Assuming that `biome` truly has a latent subject-specific effect the fixed-effect terms would capture the among-biome variation due to `X1`, etc. Any further variation would that be captured by `(1|biome)` (which understandably might come out as redundant in which case it should be excluded).

Comment: Again because of the implicit intercept term that R includes in formulae, this is the same as `S~(1+X1+X2+X3)*biome+(1|biome)`, so there is a redundant biome term (it's in both fixed and random effects).  You *could* use `S~(X1+X2+X3+0)*biome+(1|biome)`, but as stated above I think for practical reasons you'll be better off with biome as a fixed effect

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yeah, sure my bad, I should have wrote `~(-1/0+ X1 +...)`. Having said that using `biome` as a random effects in a `~(X1+X2+X3+0)*biome+(1|biome)` setting estimates a single number, not a full 4-by-4 VCV matrix. I am asking all this cause you did not raise this point [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121593/using-the-same-variable-as-a-fixed-and-random-effect-in-mixed-effect-models) and I am trying to understand if it is not OK in the current case because we deal with intercepts but it was OK in the previous thread as we dealt with slopes only.

Comment: It's OK to use `a + (a|biome)`, whether `a` is categorical or continuous; if `a` is categorical with many levels it leads to large RE models.  `a + (1|a)` is redundant (if `a` is categorical) or nonsensical (if `a` is continuous)

Comment: Many thanks, Ben. This was the answer I was hoping for. However, that will for sure prolong the calculations. Thx!